# UILabel in UIScrollview strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

Strange issue faced today. Xcode 8.3.2 while using UIScrollView, UILabel shows outline and actual label on different place. Which also display weird in the simulator.

Anyone faced the same issue. Any solution ? I have searched google so much but found nothing.

Help me if anyone has solution.
[image: Interface builder image]

Comment: you need to set the constraints correctly

Answer (score 0):

When there is a red arrow in your view hierarchy:

[image]

It means something is wrong with your autolayout. Click on it and Xcode will provide you with the information what's wrong. In this case your scroll view needs to know size and position of your content (In your case size of the UIlabel), so it is able to stretch its content and determine if it should scroll.